# Conditional update between two tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

In the two tables below, for students and parents with the same school names: I want it to assign parent_name to student_name.

```
CREATE TABLE students2 (
     student_id CHAR(2),
     student_name VARCHAR2(30),
     student_grade NUMBER(2),
     school_name VARCHAR2(50)
)



CREATE TABLE parents (
     student_id CHAR(2),
     parent_name VARCHAR2(30),
     school_name VARCHAR2(50)
)


UPDATE students2
SET student_name = (SELECT parent_name 
                    FROM parents 
                    WHERE parents.school_name = students2.school_name)
```

When I write this query, the update is done BUT the student_names that do not meet the condition are made `NULL`. They were not supposed to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say *which* rows should be updated; see `WHERE EXISTS`.

```
UPDATE students2 a SET 
  a.student_name = (SELECT b.parent_name 
                    FROM parents b
                    WHERE b.school_name = a.school_name)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM parents c
              WHERE c.school_name = a.school_name);
```

---

Alternatively, as you didn't learn `EXISTS` yet:

```
UPDATE students2 a SET 
  a.student_name = (SELECT b.parent_name 
                    FROM parents b
                    WHERE b.school_name = a.school_name)
WHERE a.school_name IN (select c.school_name
                        FROM parents c);
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick help, it works. I also understood the query. However, the EXISTS condition has not yet been taught in the source I work with. That's why I'm a little confused 

Comment: You could've used IN, then. See modified answer, please.

Comment: This is more clear for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm having a hard time with sql. So far I have used  hibernate and I was very comfortable. But pure sql is pushing me hard. I hope I can learn...

Comment: I'm sure you can :)

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood, if you want to assign parent_name to student_name, shouldn't the query look like-

`UPDATE students2 SET student_name = (SELECT parent_name FROM parents WHERE parents.student_id= students2.student_id)`

Anyways, if I'm missing something or you already know about that, maybe you can try this for null values:

```
UPDATE students2 SET student_name =(SELECT parent_name FROM parents
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN %s IS NOT NULL
            < statements > 
        ELSE < statements >
        END
    [AND/OR] <other constraints here> )
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong